# Send message to Slack channel build with blocks using Incoming webhooks or chat.postMessage?

Tags: php, slack-api

Is it possible to send msg to Slack channel which is build in blocks using Incoming Webhook or must I use `chat.postMessage` API method?

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages containing [layout blocks](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/blocks) with any kind of message sending including

- [Incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)
- API methods like [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
- response to [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) or [interactive message](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity).

It will not work with [RTM message sending](https://api.slack.com/rtm) though, which is limited to simple text messages and also does not support secondary attachments.